# I'm having issue connecting with my local Ethereum node

Tags: web3js

```
$ node connect
(node:11804) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\User\New folder\connect.js:3
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545");
                     ^

TypeError: Web3.providers.HttpProvider is not a constructor
    at connect (C:\Users\User\New folder\connect.js:3:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\New folder\connect.js:7:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1375:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1434:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
```

Node.js v21.5.0

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment since I'm none too sure I'm correct, but after taking a quick look in the docs, I think you need to wrap the instantiation of the provider like this: `new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545");`, assuming the port details are correct.